# How to division operator scenario when denominator is zero , or both numerator and denominator are zero?

Tags: haskell, hspec

I am trying to do TDD in haskell using HSpec. So while writing special case scenario for division operator for example:

- `3 / 0 => Infinity`
- `0 / 0 => Nan`

How to test the above cases using Hspec ?

Answer (score 7):

Use the functions [**isInfinite**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:isInfinite) and [**isNaN**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:isNaN):

```
Prelude> isInfinite (3 / 0.0)
True
Prelude> isNaN (0.0/0.0)
True
```